# Prove that $\neg \left [ \exists ! x \in \mathbb{R} \exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) \right ]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

This is an exercise from Velleman's "How To Prove It". I have been struggling with the logical form of this statement, and just want to make sure that my proof is correct now.

> Show that it is *not* the case that there is a unique real number $x$ such that there is a unique real number $c$ such that $x^2 + 3x + c = 0$. (Hint: You should be able to prove that for *every* real number $x$ there is a unique real number $c$ such that $x^2 + 3x + c= 0$

$$\neg \left [ \exists ! x \in \mathbb{R} \exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0)  \right ]$$
$$\neg \left [ \exists x \in \mathbb{R} \left(\exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) \wedge \neg \exists y \in \mathbb{R}(\exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) \wedge x \neq y)\right )  \right ]$$
$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \left( \neg \exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) \vee \exists y \in \mathbb{R}(\exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) \wedge x \neq y)\right ) $$
$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \left( \exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) \rightarrow \exists y \in \mathbb{R}(\exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) \wedge x \neq y)\right ) $$

Proof: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Suppose that $\exists ! c \in \mathbb{R} (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) $. Let y = x + 1. Clearly $x \neq y$. Now let $c =  - x^2 -5x - 4$.

Then
\begin{align}
y^2 + 3y + c &=(x+1)^2 + 3(x+1) - x^2 - 5x -4 \\ 
&= x^2 + 2x + 1 + 3x + 3 - x^2 -5x - 4 \\
&= 0
\end{align}
To show that $z$ is unique, let $d \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary such that $y^2 + 3y + d = 0$. Then subtracting $y^2 + 3y$ from both sides of the equation yields $d = -y^2 - 3y = -(x+1)^2 - 3(x+1) = -x^2 -5x - 4 = c. \square$

Comment: It is already sufficient to show that for $x=0$ and $x=1$ (lets say), there is a unique $c$. $x$ cannot be unique anymore then.

Comment: @Peter Ah, I see. Drawing a contradiction would be much easier on the eyes. Is the above proof correct though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed do this by contradiction is just a one line proof, but what you did is still correct as a direct proof, if we write as following might make it easier to read.

Let $P(x)\equiv\exists ! c \in \mathbb{R}, (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) $
\begin{align}
&\neg(\exists ! x \in \mathbb{R},P(x))\\
\equiv&\exists^{>1}x\in\mathbb{R},P(x)\lor \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\neg P(x)\\
\equiv&\exists x\in\mathbb{R},P(x)\to\exists^{>1}x\in\mathbb{R},P(x)
\end{align}
Assume $\exists x\in\mathbb{R},P(x)$, have $\exists x\in\mathbb{R},\exists ! c \in \mathbb{R}, x^2 + 3x + c = 0$, fix $x$ and since that $$(x+1)^2+3(x+1)=x^2+5x+4$$
take $c_0=c-2x-4$, this proves $(x+1)^2+3(x+1)+c_0=0$, where $c_0$ is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint, one can show that in fact, the statement holds after removing $\neg$ and the square brackets, and replacing the first $\exists!$ with $\forall$.

For any real number $x$, there is obviously a unique real number $c$ for which $x^2+3x+c=0$, namely $c=-x^2-3x$.

Hence, the statement "$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\, \exists! c \in \mathbb{R}\, x^2+3x+c=0$" is true, and so certainly, "$\exists! x \in \mathbb{R}\, \exists! c \in \mathbb{R}\, x^2+3x+c=0$" is false.